# How do i download code files of the website from wordpress.com?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-thesis-theme

i have one website which is developed on 
Wordpress.com.

website is not deployed on a Server.

It has no FTP or CPanel details.

I have only WP-Admin details, so from this how can i download the source file (code file).

Comment: use this plugin to download plugins and themes https://wordpress.org/plugins/download-plugins-dashboard/

Comment: Mate, i want to get all the file in locally in my system using WP-Admin access, as i don't have  FTP or CPanel.

Comment: you can install plugin via wp-admin?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Move from wordpress.com to your own WP install?

Comment: @Vel Ican install plugins from the admin panel.

Comment: @RiddleMeThis I want to set up entire project into my local system, but i don't have FTP or Cpanel details. I have only admin panel details.

Comment: then install this plugin wordpress.org/plugins/download-plugins-dashboard

Comment: @vel Ok & how can we download the wordpress file of the project?

Comment: did you installed this plugin wordpress.org/plugins/download-plugins-dashboard in wordpress.com?

Comment: @vel No, yet I have not installed the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best you can do.  [A guide from Wordpress.com](https://move.wordpress.com/).

I would start off by [downloading a copy of wordpress](https://wordpress.org/download/).  Then follow the steps in the guide.